# How to prevent soft keyboard from pushing up only the toolbar and BottomTabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

I have tried many solution to prevent the toolbar and bottom tab layout not to push up when edittext come in focus or when keyboard is opened but i am not be able to find the solution. In android manifest i have used adjustpan and adjustresize also but not be able to get the desired solution. It will be great help if anyone suggest any solution to my problem. I just want the my toolbar and bottom tab layout does not push up and remain on their position while view can push between these two.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for activity in Manifest file ?

Comment: yes i have tried it but still my toolbar is pushing up if i use adjustpan

Comment: try stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize

Comment: tried this but in this keyboard is overlapping the edittext

Answer (score 0):

Because of the soft toolbar being pushed up by the soft keyboard I ended up -
 in my app - creating a new Android activity (so not a fragment embedded in a tab layout) with the form.

Whilst this is not a perfect solution, at least there is no soft toolbar in the activity with the form with EditView's.

You will lose the navigation though. So the user of the form activitywill need to press the back button to go back to the main application.